# laravel base64_encode ajax response returns 0

Tags: laravel, base64, array-map

I have an ajax endpoint that returns a collection. Before I return the collection, I change the id of every model inside with its base64 encoded string. However, it returns 0 instead of the string. What am I doing wrong? The ID is set.

```
$trainees->map(function ($trainee) {
    $trainee['id'] = base64_encode($trainee['id']);
});
```

If I return this inside a blade file, everything works fine...

Comment: Where are you returning this?  All I see is a map function.  You might want to add some additional controller code.

Comment: I am returning this inside my vue project. However, the response contains the 0, so there seems to be no bug in my js (Crome dev tools.

Comment: I mean, you have no return statement here, either outside the map or inside the map, both would be errors.